# ORM - Get type of base class in static context?

Tags: c#

I am trying to create a micro ORM, but am stuck on a small issue.

I am trying to get the class name that is using the current class as a base class. I am maybe do this using reflection, but is there a way I can make this work in the desired way? And not have to pass the table name to Query()

The concept of a model is as shown,

```
public class Player : BaseModel
{
        
}
```

Base model:

```
public class BaseModel
{
    public static IQueryBuilder Query(string tableName)
    {
        return new QueryBuilder(null,  new QueryBuilderOptions(tableName));
    }
}
```

Comment: Make BaseModel generic, and `Player : BaseModel<Player>` ?

Comment: `GetType().Name`

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay GetType() is an instance method, and in a static method you don't have access to the type like that.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Ah yes, I missed the static.

Comment: Hi @LasseV.Karlsen thanks for your answer, that has given me what I want. If you would like to post an answer I will happily accept it on here.